# Microsoft BotBuilder, markdown named links rendered as URLs in Slack

Tags: c#, botframework, slack

When sending a link to the user using the syntax:

`[Microsoft Web](http://microsoft.com)`

Slacks only render

`http://microsoft.com`

as the link, ignoring "Microsoft Web" text. Skypes or Bot Emulator renders the link correctly, using the passed text.

Using the slack syntax (https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_urls) it works correctly, e.g.:

`<http://www.microsoft.com|Microsoft Web>`

renders the link using the text "Microsoft Web".

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you give an example of your code.

Answer (score 4):

As [this page](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages#bot-message-formatting) explains, Slack is not interested in supporting Markdown. This means that it also wont work for you bot.

I suggest that you detect the channel the user is using and use that information to create a custom message/link when sending to Slack.

Comment: As the answer says, this problem is coming from Slack and according to this response https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2834 Microsoft is not going to do anything to handle it in the bot framework. So I assume this is the right answer.